# passing props to vue 3 composable isn't reactive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm trying to pass a component prop to a composable and in the composable is a computed based on one of the component props. For some reason, the computed function is never called when the prop changes.

```
import { toRefs } from 'vue';

export default {
  props: {
    aProp: String,
  },
  setup(props) {
    // this doesn't work
    const { aProp } = toRefs(props);
    const { aHasChanged } = useA(aProp);

    return {
      aHasChanged,
    };
  },
};
```

and the composable:

```
import { computed } from 'vue';
function useComposable(aProp) {
  const aHasChanged = computed(() => {
    return aProp === '';
  });

  return {
    aHasChanged,
  };
}

export { useComposable };
```

stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-yfh8fb-xaspss?file=composables%2Fa.js

Answer (score 1):

Computed function isn't triggered because `aProp.value` is not accessed; there's no way in JavaScript how Vue reactivity could be implemented just by accessing `aProp` parameter value and not its properties.

`aProp` is a ref inside `useComposable`, and it should be:

```
      const aHasChanged = computed(() => {
        return aProp.value !== ''; 
      });
```